# Why is $l^p$ meagre in $l^q$ ?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have to prove that for $p < q$,  $l^p$ is meagre in $l^q$, which I did by finding a sequence of nowhere dense sets whose union is equal to $l^p$. But then I wondered if there was the following much simpler way:

Let $E$ be a normed vector space. If $F$ is a linear subspace of $E$ and $\overline F \neq E$ then F is nowhere dense and therefore $F$ is meagre.

Can you apply this to $F=l^p$ and $E=l^q$?

Comment: But $l^p$ is dense in $l^q$, so you cannot apply it in your case.

Comment: @GEdgar thank you! could you explain why that is? or like give the idea of the proof?

Comment: Even the subset of sequences that are eventually zero is dense in $l^q$.

Comment: @GEdgar ohh yeah that makes sense, thanks :)